# Simulate Mouse move/click/keyPress in an application that is not active

Tags: keypress, simulate

I know how to simulate mouse and keyboard events, but they act as if the user did them, so they will affect the window that is active. What I need is to simulate one of those inputs, but in a Window that is not active.

I'm not saying that it is minimized, imagine for example, you have msPaint, and notepad. Notepad is in front of paint. And you want to simulate mouse clicks in certain coordinates of the paint window, but without setting it active, making it possible for the user to keep using notepad which is in fron of paint.

Is this possible at all?
Thanks!

Comment: What tools/languages are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might do the following:

1) get the `HWND` of the window inside which you want to simulate events. In order to do this you can use the `FindWindow` function, which takes two parameters, one being the window's class name (you can use `NULL`) and the other the name of the window (see MSDN documentation for details);

2) send a message to the desired window using `SendMessage` function. The parameters are: the previous obtained window handle (`HWND`), the message (which can be for example `WM_KEYDOWN`, or `WM_MOUSEMOVE`, `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` etc.), the `WPARAM` of the message (which in case of `WM_KEYDOWN` is the virtual key code of the key) and finally the `LPARAM` of the message (which in case of `WM_KEYDOWN` is quite complex and you should check MSDN for details).

In my opinion this is sufficient for what you intend to do.

Comment: Did the OP have any success with this approach? I've read my way through some hefty threads that claim method 2) does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you knew JAVA you could use the robots class.

> This class is used to generate native system input events for the purposes of test automation, self-running demos, and other applications where control of the mouse and keyboard is needed

[Java robots class](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html)

Maybe theres something simular in .net?

Comment: Don't see how you can use the Robots class to send key presses to an inactive window