# Getting image contents of obstructed window

Tags: c++, windows, screen-capture

Is it possible to get image contents of an obstructed window without bringing it to the front? Also, is it possible to send mouse clicks to a specific locations of such window using Windows API? Would the realization be different on Windows XP and Windows 7?
What functions I would need and where can I read more about that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows GDI can assist you on the screenshot task. There's some VB code [here](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=312702) to get you started.

There's a lot of material on how to simulate mouse clicks:

http://tomicki.net/mouse.clicker.php

[Simulate Mouse move/click/keyPress in an application that is not active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806376/simulate-mouse-move-click-keypress-in-an-application-that-is-not-active)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171548.aspx

Comment: Thanks. Would you happen to know whether the code would work on Windows XP if written on Windows 7?