# Emulate User Activity

Tags: windows, emulation

I want to emulate user activity in Windows machine like left mouse click and further more I would like to perform a pre-defined steps repeatability.

Is there any tool available for that?

Please suggest me an easy and nice way to do it?

Comment: I believe the tool you are looking for is a monkey

Comment: Then may be u can help me!!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used AutoIT v3 for a long time and highly recommend it:

http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml

Recently I've been using Sikuli, and it seems to be a bit faster than AutoIT and is also definitely worth a try:

http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/sikuli/

Sikuli is based on taking screenshots to define the areas you want to click and seems to have much less of a learning curve, so if you aren't a programmer or prefer not to code that is your best bet. AutoIT is primarily a scripting language, so you are essentially scripting user actions through code.

Comment: AutoIt comes with a tool (AU3Record) that allows you to "record" actions on screen to help put together scripts for automation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be nice, you got to do it yourself:

[Getting image contents of obstructed window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462334/getting-image-contents-of-obstructed-window/3462361#3462361)

There's a lot of materials out there that shows how to simulate mouse events using the Windows API.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to write your own program to do this:

[`SendInput` (newer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310.aspx) or [`mouse_event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646260.aspx) and [`keybd_event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646304.aspx) (simpler)

If you're looking for an existing program, then superuser is a better place to ask than stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [white](http://white.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex

Answer (score 0):

AutoHotkey is the tool you are looking for. It emulates user activity in Windows and more... It is open source and has a wonderful community support:

http://www.autohotkey.com/